# Crash while trying to do bit shift

Tags: rust

I am trying to run this rust code

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

fn ip_to_int(addr: Ipv4Addr) -> u32 {
        let ip = addr.octets();
        (ip[0] as u32) << 24 + (ip[1] as u32) << 16 + (ip[2] as u32) << 8 + (ip[3] as u32)
    }

fn main() {
    let ip = Ipv4Addr::new(74, 125, 227, 0);
    println!("{}", ip_to_int(ip));
}
```

This crashes with

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'shift operation overflowed', test.rs:5
```

I did typecast everything to 32 bit ints and no shift is larger than 32 bits. Why does it crash? Also, isn't the compiler supposed to catch this and prevent compilation?

```
Abhishek@Abhisheks-MacBook-Pro-2:~$ rustc --version
rustc 1.1.0-nightly (21f278a68 2015-04-23) (built 2015-04-24)
```

Comment: The overflow is saying arithmetic overflow, viz. that bits have been lost. Given that `ip` is `[u8; 4]`, no part of that expression should be capable of causing overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence), operator `+` as a stronger precedence than operator `<<`, meaning that your expression is actually parsed like this:

```
(ip[0] as u32) << (24 + (ip[1] as u32)) << (16 + (ip[2] as u32)) << (8 + (ip[3] as u32))
```

Which can pretty easily overflow.

You need to add the appropriates brackets:

```
((ip[0] as u32) << 24) + ((ip[1] as u32) << 16) + ((ip[2] as u32) << 8) + (ip[3] as u32)
```